# Xamarin Forms stacklayout TapGestureRecognizer command not called

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, navigation

I have added a command on StackLayout using TapGestureRecognizer but it didn't called on viewmodel class.

**Here is xaml code:**

```
<StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="0">
    <Image Source="edit_black" WidthRequest="20" />
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding EditServiceCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

**ViewModel class Command method:**

```
public ICommand EditServiceCommand
        {
            get => new Command((item) => { _popupNavigation.PushAsync(new AddServicePopup("edit"), true); });
        }
```

Comment: Did you already assign the page binding context to your view model?

Comment: Yes i used prism

Comment: How did you register the viewmodel in prism? Is your viewmodel's constructor called?

Comment: Viewmodel is working, i am able to polulate list from viewmodel.

Comment: if you are using Prism, you might want to use DelegateCommand

Answer (score 0):

Please update your view model command code to the following

```
 private ICommand _EditServiceCommand;
 public ICommand EditServiceCommand => _EditServiceCommand ?? (_EditServiceCommand = new Command((item) =>
    {
        _popupNavigation.PushAsync(new AddServicePopup("edit"), true);
    }));
```

Comment: Working for me. There might be some other issue.
Please try sharing some more of your code

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the command what type `item` is.

```
public ICommand EditServiceCommand
{
     get => new Command<CommandParameterType>((item) => { _popupNavigation.PushAsync(new AddServicePopup("edit"), true); });
}
```

But in your code you're not using item so you can call the command without a CommandParameter.

```
get => new Command(() => _popupNavigation.PushAsync(new AddServicePopup("edit"), true));
```